# Looking for an English equivalent to the relatively new French word "bientraitance," which means the act or practice of treating (someone/people) well

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

The French have coined a new term "bientraitance" which is a noun that means "treating people well" or "treating people respectfully or properly." I don't think there is an English equivalent (doesn't that speak legions???) but I think it's time we came up with one, just as the French have done. Have you wonderful people any suggestions? Many thanks in advance for your thoughts on this!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the requirements of StackExchange is that you have attempted some research on your own, and for word requests, you should indicate how the word would be used in a sentence. For example, I do not understand what the benefit would be of *having [beintraitance]* over *being respectful* or *showing civility*. For additional guidance, I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help].

Comment: Google Translate rather lamely offers only "positive treatment," which is not good input for an e-thesaurus. And other than that, going from definition or sense to word is much harder than the other way round using standard resources. It takes a human. We accommodate such queries routinely.

Comment: ['mutual respect'](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/this-google-chrome-extension-replaces-political-correct[ness-with-something-more-accurate_us_55c82605e4b0923c12bd4a91)

Answer (score 5):

For an abstract noun, I think *[decency](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/decency)* or *[civility](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/civility)* would already fit the bill. (Links are to thefreedictionary.com, a dictionary aggregator site.) Both are abstract nouns formed from adjectives *(decent* and *civil),* but so I suspect is your French word (from *bientraitant.)*

Oddly, several dictionaries list only *decentness* as the nominalization of *decent,* though *decency* is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decency%2Cdecentness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 0):

Hospitality.

This word is used in the same context, though literally it points towards treating guests, visitors or strangers with generosity but it surely conveys the same connotation.

Answer (score 0):

*Benevolence* stands out most to me--and probably struck me given the similarity of the sound of the last syllable of both words.

Not only am I apt to use this word from my own personal background and understanding, but [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/benevolence) describes it as "desire to do good to others; goodwill; charitableness".  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benevolence) lends "disposition to do good" and "an act of kindness".

Answer (score 0):

I would use the terms "having class" or "being classy". The sense of the word as relates to behavior is fairly open to interpretation; some people take the traditional sense of being elegant and stylish and conflate classy with *classist*. However, there are several citations for this definition of the word that I think fits and gives a more positive connotation for the behavior or people described than other alternatives.

> b :  having or reflecting high standards of personal behavior

<sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/classy). See also [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=classy)"not crude or disgusting or dirty or depressing; a deeper, more meaningful word for 'cool'" and [MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/classy) "behave in an appropriate way in every situation"</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If I want to treat a stranger well I start by treating them ***respectfully*** - in the sense of being esteemed, honoured, amd/or highly thought of (OED).